# How to manage a categorical variable with many distinct values(500) in Machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

Let say I have a dataset 15 columns and it has 2 category columns. These columns has many distinct values around *200*. If we apply **onehot/dummy varibale** then it create ***400*** columns(for 2 columns above mentioned). Is it good way to handle or is there any better way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "one size fits all" answer to this question. It depends on the type and context of data, domain or business need of the data and many other factors. However, here are few suggestions that can be considered.

1. Perform binning on the data. Eg - a list of city names can be binned into fewer categories based on location (part of the country), population size, weather conditions and so on. Again, it'll depend on the business context. This will help reduce the number of categories.
2. Apply label encoding on the data. Label encoding usually works well on tree based algorithms rather than one-hot encoding.
3. If one-hot encoding is absolutely necessary, then apply that, especially for linear models. If reducing the number of features becomes necessary later, PCA can be used for the same.

So to summarize - if the solution doesn't look "obvious", then try all options and see which is working best.

In addition, the special case of a "new category" on test data must be considered, else the model will fail in production.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Hi , very interesting comment about Label encoding doing better for tree based models. Can you please elaborate on that? Any references you found by any chance?